# Problem while installing keras through anaconda prompt?

Tags: keras, installation, deep-learning, anaconda, data-science

I installed keras by using this action on anaconda prompt "conda install -c conda-forge keras". However, when installing Keras the anaconda prompt closed. Now, whenever I try to start the anaconda prompt it closes after 1 second and displays a short message for a short time
[image]

Answer (score 0):

pip install keras is always safest.

To solve your problem, as the error says, download the visual studio community from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

When done, open visual studio installer, under visual studio community you should have a 'modify' button, install all C++ workloads and individual components depending on your machine.

You should then be able to access anaconda application by typing for example 'jupyter notebook' in the prompt. normally.

Comment: Nothing happens, Still my anaconda prompt is getting closed and showing the same error